# Gerenciar botão voltar entre fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo para a faculdade no qual eu estou usando fragments para todas as minhas telas, por questões de reutilização. O problema é que não consigo controlar o comportamento do botão de voltar entre os fragments.

Dentro de um fragment, eu chamo outro fragment, porém quando aperto o botão de voltar, o primeiro fragment não retorna, mas sim a activity é encerrada. Li que poderia adicionar o fragment no stack que gerencia o voltar, porém isso não parece ser possível dentro de fragment para fragment.

O código que eu pesquisei é esse:

```
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
....
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Para remover o fragment do stack:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        this.finish();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Retirei essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635594, onde o autor deixou explícito que funciona entre activities. No meu caso, que estou chamando um fragment dentro de outro fragment, qual seria a opção mais indicada? Creio que o comportamento que eu desejo, resumidamente, é esse:

> Activity 1 carrega Fragment 1 automaticamente. O Fragment 1 pode
>   chamar o Fragment 2 em determinado momento, sendo que quando o
>   Fragment 2 for encerrado (seja por entrada de botão do próprio
>   fragment [ok/cancelar] tanto quanto por botão voltar do aparelho) ele
>   deve retornar ao Fragment 1.

Comment: Usando essa alternativa do backstack dentro do fragment 1 não está funcionando? Exibe algum erro? A princípio eu não vejo nenhum problema nessa solução...

Existe algum impedimento de não delegar essa substituição dos fragmentos para a `Activity`?

Poderia também detalhar melhor o trecho em que substitui os fragmentos (caso tenha implementado)?

Comment: Aparentemente os erros se corrigiram sozinhos. No que eu postei a pergunta, funcionou. Vou postar minha solução em breve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema se resolveu sozinho, mas depois fui entender como funcionava o `FragmentManager`, resolvendo o problema da seguinte maneira:

Dentro do Fragment 1, chamo o Fragment 2, adicionando ele ao stack:

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    Fragment newUsr = new NewUserFragment();
    // essa linha é responsável por adicionar o fragment ao stack
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.replace(R.id.container_login, newUsr);
    transaction.commit();
```

No fragment aberto, consigo voltar ao primeiro usando um botão na ActionBar com o seguinte código:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu_newuser_cancel:
            // essa linha é responsável por fechar o fragment,
            // simulando um toque do botão voltar, ao mesmo tempo em
            // que o remove do stack
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            break;
        }
```

Com isso, consegui fazer a transição entre fragments a partir de fragments sem problemas com fragments se sobrepondo. Vale adicionar aqui que, em alguns casos, os itens da `ActionBar` estavam sendo duplicados, resolvi isso adicionando `menu.clear()`; dentro do método `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_newuser, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Com isso consegui realizar a transição entre os fragments de maneira eficiente e sem problemas.