# Retornar a um Fragment anterior a partir de qualquer Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho uma Activity principal na qual são chamados alguns fragments:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listas);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    FragmentUm fragment_um = new FragmentUm();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment, fragment_um).commit();
}
```

Ao carregar o fragment_um nesta Activity eu tenho um RecyclerView onde eu clico em um item que pode me direcionar para a activity_detalhes ou chamar o fragment_dois:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
FragmentDois fragment_dois = new FragmentDois();

ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment_dois).commit();
```

Ao carregar o fragment_dois eu tenho um RecyclerView que ao clicar em um item da lista pode me direcionar para o fragment_tres ou para a activity_detalhes. O fragment_tres eu tenho a mesma situação.

No manifest a activity principal está configurada para mostrar o botão home na toolbar:

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

No entanto, se estiver com o fragment_dois carregado na activity e clicar no botão home, não consigo voltar para o fragment_um. A mesma coisa acontece se estiver no fragment_tres e clicar no botão home, não consigo voltar para o fragment_dois.

Tentei utilizar `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` ou `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()` dentro do `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` mas não deu certo.

Minha pergunta é, o que tenho que fazer para voltar para o fragment anterior a partir de qualquer um deles?

**Fiz algumas alterações no código:**

Na activity principal uso a classe onBackPressed() para quando clicar no ícone home, através do onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item), voltar para o fragment anterior:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Retirei do manifest a configuração que citei anteriormente. No onViewCreated dos fragments implementei esse código para mostrar programaticamente o ícone home na ActionBar. No fragment 1 ele fica false e nos outros true:

```
ActionBar actionbar=((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Está funcionando, no entanto está mostrando um alerta de que getSupportActionBar e setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled podem gerar um NullPointerException. Tem como resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente você está certo, em vez de utilizar `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` e `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()` dentro do `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, utilize `getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`, esta solução funcionou no questionamento [Gerenciar botão voltar entre fragments](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16729/gerenciar-bot%C3%A3o-voltar-entre-fragments)

Porém esta função é para ser utilizada no `ActionBar` e não no botão `Home`.

Comment: Tentei utilizar o exemplo que você indicou mas no meu caso não funcionou. Com esse exemplo, ao clicar no botão home não acontece nada.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a maneira mais correta de resolução do problema que apontei, mas resolvi da seguinte maneira:

Nos fragments inclui:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {

    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof Activity){
        mActivity =(Activity) context;
    }
}

public static AppCompatActivity getAppCompActivity(Context context) {
    if (context == null)
        return null;
    if (context instanceof AppCompatActivity) {
        return (AppCompatActivity) context;
    }
    return null;
}
```

E ainda nos fragments em onViewCreated:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getAppCompActivity(mActivity).getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Em MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home){
        onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Consigo voltar entre os fragments e não tenho mais alerta de NullPointerException.
Talvez ainda caibam melhorias, mas no momento atendeu minhas necessidades.